# It looks like nSubsitute is just testing itself rather than my code

Tags: nsubstitute

Possibly stupid question. In the docs they give this example

```
calculator.Add(1, 2).Returns(3);
Assert.That(calculator.Add(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(3));
```

Am I testing that the actual calculator returns 3 or just that the substitute does? If the latter, what is the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where my brain went, but I seem to have momentarily lost the point of a mock. Saying

```
calculator.Add(1, 2).Returns(3)
```

is the wrong example. A much better example would be

```
var person = database.GetMember(123) returns "Jesse Liberty"
```

not so that I can test the mock, but so that I can test code that depends on the database.

Obvious, I know, but sometimes the brain just shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the example on the front page (https://nsubstitute.github.io/), they are just showing that it works, it is not part of your test really.

Comment: When you write
calculator.Add(1, 2).Returns(3);
aren't you saying that the mock will always return 3 when you pass in 1 and 2? How do you access the actual calculator to see if it also returns 3?
I read what they have as "This mock always returns 3 when you add 1 and 2, now test that when you add 1 and 2 the mock returns 3" - which seems pointless. What I want is "this mock returns 3 when you add 1 and 2, now check if that works in the program itself." What am I missing?

Comment: You don't want to access the real calculator, that's why you use nsubstitute. For example, you have a view model on a mvvm app that uses a service returning a list of Buddies, but you don't want to access the real data source, you use nsubstitute to mock the returned list. But you don't assert that, you will write the test about the view model. 
Additional comment, you can also check what methods are called, but I don't think you want to do that on tests, you are coupling the test to the implementation of the mocked object

Comment: Of course! Boy did I confuse myself. Thanks for getting me back on track.  -- what do you think of nSubstitute vs. Moq so far?

Comment: Is there a way to accept a comment as the answer?

Comment: I don't think you can accept a comment as the answer :)

Comment: nSubstitute vs Moq, I didn't used nSubstitue yet, but I will let you know as soon as I do some testing ;)